# HTML  response when passing an Object in Zend Controller using end_Json_Encoder::encode

Tags: json, zend-framework, jquery

I Have two problem in this Case :
I want to pass a JSON object that i created in Zend Controller

```
public function exampleAction() {
    $answers = array();
    for($i = 0 ; $i < 3 ; $i++)
     {
                $answer = new Answer();
                $answer->answer_id = 5 ; // for example
                $answer->thanked = 'true';// for example
                $answers[] = $answer;
     }

    echo Zend_Json_Encoder::encode($answers);
}
```

the Jquery Post function is :

```
 $.post(
      "/memberactions/getthanks/",
      {values:values},
        function(res){   
           alert(123);     
        } 
      , 'json')
```

**First Question** :
why the return response is HTML ? the response must be in JSON ?

**Second Question** 
the HTML response is like this

```
[{"__className":"Answer","thanked":"true","answer_id":"5"}]
```

How can I make the response like this :

```
 - answer 
     thanked : true
     answer_id : 5
```

as a **JSON Object** without the **__className:"Answer"** (does it hurt to have the class name in the response) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Have you disabled layout, viewRenderer etc.? Also, you should send appropriate headers. You can do all this at once using the JSON action helper:

   `$this->_helper->json($answers);`
2. You could provide a `toArray()` method in `Answer`, which would return an array of relevant properties and then use it in your action:

   `$answers[] = $answer->toArray();`